# Convert complex json into c# Object

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am working on a pretty complex json. I have converted whatever needed till now using JSON.Net, but i am stuck in a part of this json. Following is the snippet of the json which i am unable to resolve.

```
{
    "name": "BIRTHDATE",
    "path": "BIRTHDATE",
    "locale": "IFA_EN_GB",
    "hasAnswer": true,
    "isSatisfied": false,
    "triggeredLines": [],
    "answers": [
        "100"
    ],
    "validationErrors": {
        "100": [
            "Please enter a valid date."
        ],
                "10": [
            "Please enter a valid date."
        ].....
    },
    "definition": null
},
```

How can i resolve this section.

```
"validationErrors": {
        "100": [
            "Please enter a valid date."
        ],
                "10": [
            "Please enter a valid date."
        ].....
    }
```

Class created for deserialization.

```
public class Question
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string path { get; set; }
    public string locale { get; set; }
    public bool hasAnswer { get; set; }
    public bool isSatisfied { get; set; }
    public List<object> triggeredLines { get; set; }
    public List<string> answers { get; set; }
    public object validationErrors { get; set; }
    public object definition { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Please show your code and where specifically you´re stuck.

Comment: create a class like this to deserialize.

 public class Question
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string path { get; set; }
        public string locale { get; set; }
        public bool hasAnswer { get; set; }
        public bool isSatisfied { get; set; }
        public List<object> triggeredLines { get; set; }
        public List<string> answers { get; set; }
        public object validationErrors { get; set; }
        public object definition { get; set; }

    }

Comment: What do you mean by the dots at the end ?? After the last shown in the second snippet `]`

Comment: ... means there can be many other properties as well.

problem is that there in no fix number of properties inside validationErrors property. It can be any name, and any number.

Comment: Please add your code directly into the question. It´s very hard to read it within the comments.

Comment: just added the class in code

Comment: `public Dictionary<string, string[]> validationErrors`

Comment: Paste your JSON here.:
https://app.quicktype.io/#l=cs&r=json2csharp
The rest it will do on its own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This json:

```
"validationErrors": {
        "100": [
            "Please enter a valid date."
        ],
                "10": [
            "Please enter a valid date."
        ].....
    }
```

Is a `Dictionary<string,string[]>`. so your `Question` object should have

```
public Dictionary<string,string[]> validationErrors { get; set; }
```